# Errno 2 No such file or directory: 'azuredeploy.json'

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code

I'm new in coding so keep on getting [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'azuredeploy.json' when deploying arm template on Azure.

Followed all the steps on Microsoft learn but still [image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

First navigate to the directory where the manifest is present.Then use the below code:
`az deployment group create --resource-group learnStorage1 --template-file azuredeploy.json`